# Android Json Post to ServiceStack web service

Tags: java, c#, android, json

Good morning all,

I am following this json post to server [tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/), , which is so far working very well, until I hit an issue saving the post to a c# service stack web service.

When I debug the `json = jsonObject.toString();` it returns the following valid json.

```
{"name":"Test Name","country":"Test Country","twitter":"Test Twitter"}
```

As a general test, my web service looks like the following.

```
public object Any(String jsonString)
{           
    return jsonString;
}
```

But the response that I get back strips the " out of the string.

```
{name:Test Name,country:Test Country,twitter:Test Twitter}
```

With my limited understand of JAVA currently, I am guessing that the tutorial is correct and works fine, but the c# method just will not accept the json string correctly?

Thank you

Comment: add the parts of posting the data and processing it in your c# web service

Answer (score 0):

You should only use **Request DTO's** as the argument for ServiceStack Services (i.e. never Strings), e.g:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set ;}
    public string Country { get; set ;}
    public string Twitter { get; set ;}
}

public object Any(MyRequest request)
{           
    return request;
}
```

Returning a POCO enables ServiceStack to provide automatic [Content Negotiation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#content-negotiation) for your Response DTO's.

But returning a raw `string` in a ServiceStack Service gets written as-is, i.e. ServiceStack doesn't apply any further processing to string responses.

### [Java Add ServiceStack Reference for Android](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Java-Add-ServiceStack-Reference)

If you're looking to invoke ServiceStack Services from Android you should consider [Java Add ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Java-Add-ServiceStack-Reference) which enables a typed end-to-end API for consuming ServiceStack Services from Java/Android.